# Iterating over sub-folders and converting file format from txt to csv

Tags: python, pandas, loops

For a current project, I am planning to run through a number of sub-folders, each of them containing the files `num.txt` and `sub.txt` (but all having a different content).

I have already attempted to set up the loops through `for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):` with a subsequent conversion formula, which lets the script run through but does not yield any results.

Is there any smart tweak to activate the filetype conversion from txt to csv? The code I am currently using looks as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

# Directory of root folder
rootdir = '/Users/name/SEC'

# Iteration over sub-folders
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:

        # Converation from TXT to CSV
        read_file1 = pd.read_csv("num.txt",delimiter="\t", sep=',', error_bad_lines=False, index_col=False, dtype='unicode')
        read_file1.to_csv("df1.csv")

        read_file2 = pd.read_csv("sub.txt",delimiter="\t", sep=',', error_bad_lines=False, index_col=False, dtype='unicode')
        read_file2.to_csv("df2.csv")
```

Comment: Does this raise `FileNotFoundError`?

Comment: It is just running through without any errors. The file types are however not converted.

Comment: When your script runs, there is a current working directory. You keep converting "num.txt" in that directory. I'll post a suggested solution.

Comment: That would be great, many thanks already in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `subdirs` path to your file names. No need to do this per `dirs` or per `files` (so I made them both "_") as each subdirectory is visited once already in the for.

```
import pandas as pd
import os

# Directory of root folder
rootdir = '/Users/name/SEC'

# Iteration over sub-folders
for subdir, _, _ in os.walk(rootdir):
    # Converation from TXT to CSV
    try:
        read_file1 = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(subdir, "num.txt"),delimiter="\t", sep=',', error_bad_lines=False, index_col=False, dtype='unicode')
        read_file1.to_csv(os.path.join(subdir, "df1.csv"))
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass

    try:
        read_file2 = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(subdir, "sub.txt"),delimiter="\t", sep=',', error_bad_lines=False, index_col=False, dtype='unicode')
        read_file2.to_csv(os.path.join(subdir, "df2.csv"))
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass
```

Iterating into hidden directories like ".ipynb_checkpoints" on linux is mostly harmless but you could filter them out. When you do a top-down `os.walk`, you can remove subdirectories to be traversed by deleting them from the "dirs" list. Something similar could be done on Windows with `win32api.GetFileAttributes`.

```
for subdir, dirs, _ in os.walk(rootdir):
    dirs[:] = [name for name in dirs if not name.startswith(".")]

    ...do the rest...
```

And you could use `pathlib` to join paths more compactly. Its `Path` object overrides division to join path strings.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from pathlib import Path

# Directory of root folder
rootdir = '/Users/name/SEC'

# Iteration over sub-folders
for subdir, dirs, _ in os.walk(rootdir):
    # filter out hidden
    dirs[:] = [name for name in dirs if not name.startswith(".")]
    subdir = Path(subdir)
    # Converation from TXT to CSV
    try:
        read_file1 = pd.read_csv(subdir/"num.txt",delimiter="\t", sep=',', error_bad_lines=False, index_col=False, dtype='unicode')
        read_file1.to_csv(subdir/"df1.csv")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass

    try:
        read_file2 = pd.read_csv(subdir/"sub.txt",delimiter="\t", sep=',', error_bad_lines=False, index_col=False, dtype='unicode')
        read_file2.to_csv(subdir/"df2.csv")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I have run the code - it is yielding the error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File /Users/name/SEC/.ipynb_checkpoints/num.txt does not exist: '/Users/malte.susen/SEC/.ipynb_checkpoints/num.txt'`, hence for some reason not finding the files...

Comment: Your code assumes that all subdirectories hold these files. If that isn't the case, the operations could be put in exception handlers. I'll update.

Comment: All sub-folders contain these files. Actually the script is converting the files in all folders but nonetheless yielding the error message. I guess an exception handler should solve things, as you mentioned

Comment: Nailed it with the handler

Comment: `/Users/name/SEC/.ipynb_checkpoints/num.txt` exists? The error message says it doesn't. If you are running on linux ".pynb_checkpoints" may not be visible when doing something like "ls" (the rule in linux is that names starting with a "." are hidden) but they'll still show up in the program level list commands.

Comment: `/.ipynb_checkpoints` is not a visible folder. Good call regarding hidden folders that were set by Jupyter

Answer (score 1):

You keep reading and writing the same two files. All you need to do is to complete the path you hand to `pd.read_csv`.

```py
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir): 
    read_file1 = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(subdir, "num.txt"),delimiter="\t", sep=',', 
                 error_bad_lines=False, index_col=False, dtype='unicode')
    read_file1.to_csv(os.path.join(subdir, "df1.csv"))
```

Comment: and you might want to pass `index=False` to `.to_csv` to match what you had in the text files

Comment: Thanks for your input - I have tried the code - the line `read_file1 = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(rootdir, dir, "num.txt"),delimiter="\t", sep=',', error_bad_lines=False, index_col=False, dtype='unicode')` is yielding a syntaxt error. I am currently checking for the causes...

Comment: No need for that second `dirs` loop. `os.walk` visits all of the directories.

Comment: I couldn't remember what os.walk returns exactly, it should be fine now.